# How can I insert data into Firebase daily?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a use case where I need to enter new data into Firebase daily. It doesn't make sense for the client to do this work. It involves a user being able to create tasks, and each task should have the ability to be completed daily by the user. So after task creation by the user, data will be created for that day in which the user can complete. However, at 00:00:00 of the next day, new data should be created.

What is the best way to accomplish this using Firebase?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [Firebase's Admin Database API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start).

This would allow you to write to the database for each of your users from your own server without using the client. However you would have to setup the scheduling yourself, getting this to work would depend on how you setup your server.

Another way would be to use a scheduled notification through Firebase's [Cloud Messaging service](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/), to notify each client to perform the database writing task at the same time everyday, however this would involve using the client and it may be annoying for the user to receive a notification everyday.

Comment: Good links. To clarify, there is no way to do this without setting up a separate server, correct?

Comment: Actually I've just looked at Zapier and they may provide an integration for you the won't involve your own server: https://zapier.com/app/editor/template/10613, this would be for writing to an individual user's record. Other than this yes I believe you would need to setup your own server.